# Jenkins jobs not showing up on Jenkins dashboard

Tags: jenkins

I have my all my jobs configurations present in the Jobs folder inside Jenkins folder. In the same way, projects are present inside the Workspace folder. But, the jobs are not showing up on Jenkins dashboard.

Previously all the jobs were showing up, but after upgrading Jenkins, I am facing this issue.

Comment: What about the plugins and configurations? Are they present?

Comment: No....plugins and configurations are not present as well

Comment: What happens if you downgrade Jenkins?